# Error in http://localhost:8000/ in my new symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in symfony and created new symfony project for the first time but when I navigate to http://localhost:8000/ it gives error message:

> Warning: require(index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php
>   on line 42
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'index.php'
>   (include_path='.;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64/PEAR/pear')
>   in
>   myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php
>   on line 42

I use PHP-7.1 version

Comment: Well, the error says, that you don't have a index.php file. Do you have a file with that name? It is always helpful to provide the code, which caused the error.

Comment: If you are using 7.1 then why does your error say 5.6?  Check your php config.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an issue with Symfony. See:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25515

For now, try installing Symfony 3.4 with the @dev tag.